# What is a rank-1 constraint and why is it non-convex?

Tags: convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

When an optimal power flow problem is formulated using Semi-definite programming method, the equivalent OPF problem contains one constraint
X or W = vv^H
where v is a vector of bus voltages and H is the complex conjugate transpose operator (v = [v1 v2 .... vn]^T where (1,2,...n) are buses indexes)
In various publications, authors say that this particular constraint is a rank-1 constraint and it is a non-convex.
I want to know how is this constraint a rank-1 constraint (What is the actual meaning of rank-1 constraint)? Further, how is this constraint non-convex?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2899775

Comment: What makes it non-convex is the fact that it is a set of quadratic **equality** constraints. If you had an inequality constraint, then perhaps it could be made convex (via the Schur complement).

Answer (score 1):

It is called a rank-1 constraint because it means that the matrix $X=xx^H$ has rank 1. The constraint is not convex because the set of matrices of rank 1 (and say symmetric, if you wish) is not convex.

Comment: Just to elaborate a bit, $xx^{H}$ is a matrix of size $n$ by $n$ whose rows are all multiples of $x^{H}$, and thus has rank equal to one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now. I got it why X is a rank-1 matrix. Is there some proof which shows why a rank 1 matrix is non-convex?