# How can we show/prove that a rank-$1$ matrix is non-convex?

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization, matrix-rank, rank-1-matrices

In my optimization problem, I have a matrix $X = v v^H$ where $H$ denotes the complex conjugate transpose and $v \in \mathbb C^n$. This is a rank-$1$ matrix. In the published literature, it is mentioned that rank-$1$ matrix is also non-convex but I am unable to understand this. Can someone explain this to me why rank-$1$ matrix is also non-convex?

Comment: How can a matrix be convex?

Comment: You will easily find two $2\times 2$ rank-1 matrices whose certain convex combination is not a rank-1 matrix.

Comment: @copper.hat: Well, it's shaped like a rectangle, and rectangles are convex...

Comment: Are you asking to show that the collection of rank one matrices are not convex? Note that $1$ is of rank one, and so is $-1$, but $0 = 1+(-1)$ is not.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Well, I have just one nxn matrix (X=vv^H) and I have to check how is it non-convex? I know if we have a set of matrices, we can check for some certain combinations of matrices of that set, which can provide a zero rank matrix (and thus indicates that set of matrices is non-convex).  But, I have only one nxn matrix.

Comment: You write you have an optimization problem, where you want to optimize something over the set of rank-1 matrices plus some other constraints. But that set is not convex.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by a matrix being convex. A set can be convex, a function can be convex, but a matrix is neither a set nor a function. A matrix can only be positive (semi)definite, negative (semi)definite, or indefinite. A set of matrices can be convex or nonconvex.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give this a go since I was wondering the same thing. Are you asking why the *set of* rank 1 matrices is not convex? Let's consider the following:

$x_1 = [0,1]^T$, $x_2 = [1,0]^T$. Therefore $x_1x_1^T = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ and $x_2x_2^T = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$.

We note at this point that both $x_1x_1^T$ and $x_2x_2^T$ fall into the set of rank-1 matrices. However, their combination does not, and we can demonstrate this:

$\theta x_1x_1^T + (1-\theta)x_2x_2^T = \begin{bmatrix}
1-\theta & 0 \\
0 & \theta
\end{bmatrix}$, which is a rank-2 matrix. We cannot express this in the form $x_0 x_0^T$, (because what would $x_0$ be to allow me to get $x_0 x_0^T$ as seen above?) and it does not fall into the same set as the first two matrices $x_1x_1^T$ and $x_2x_2^T$.

Therefore the set of rank-1 matrices is not convex.