# Explaining the non convexity of rank 1 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, rank-1-matrices

I understand from this post:
[How can we show/prove that a rank-$1$ matrix is non-convex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2899775/how-can-we-show-prove-that-a-rank-1-matrix-is-non-convex)
that a rank-1 matrix is non convex but I don't understand the proof. I know that the summation of two convex functions should be convex but why are we summing the ranks of two matrices? Can I treat the rank of a matrix $X$ as a function $(f(X))$? I would appreciate it if someone would explain to me how summing the rank is a valid test for testing the convexity of a rank-1 matrix?

Comment: Matrices cannot be "convex" or "non-convex", but sets of $m \times n$ matrices (being subsets of the vector space of $m \times n$ matrices) can be "convex" or "non-convex". To prove the set of rank one matrices are not convex, all you need are two rank one matrices $A$ and $B$, and a scalar $\theta \in [0, 1]$, such that $\theta A + (1 - \theta) B$ is not of rank one. The answer on the question provides such an example.

Comment: This is what I don't understand exactly! Why are we using the test that is used for testing the convexity of a function to prove that the set of rank-1 matrices is not convex? I'm very confused about this. Are $A$ and $B$ in your example represent two points or two functions or what? I know that they are matrices but I don't understand the logic behind this test. I mean is there a convexity test that involves rank of a matrix?

Comment: There is a notion of a convex function, and a convex set. They are intimately related, but they are different. A subset $C$ of a real vector space is convex if$$x, y \in C \text{ and } \theta \in [0, 1] \implies \theta x + (1 - \theta)y \in C,$$in other words, if the entire line segment between any two points in $C$ also lies in $C$. I consider this concept "more fundamental" than the convex function, though each one can be defined in terms of the other (a function is convex iff its epigraph is convex, or a set is convex iff its indicator function is convex).

Comment: In this example, the set $C$ is the set of rank one matrices. It fails the definition, because there are two rank one matrices (i.e. $x, y \in C$) and a scalar $\theta \in [0, 1]$ so that $\theta x + (1 - \theta)y$ is not rank one, i.e. not in $C$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation. I understand this point now. I have one last point that I would like to understand. If $xx^T$ yields a positive semidefinite matrix of rank-1? How can we have a semidefinite matrix (which should produce a convex cone) while the rank constraint of the same matrix is nonconvex? I'm a bit condused by this. Aren't all PSD matrices convex?

Comment: "How can we have a semidefinite matrix (which should produce a convex cone) while the rank constraint of the same matrix is nonconvex?" Again, a matrix cannot be convex or not convex. Sets of matrices can be convex or not convex. I'm not $100\%$ sure what you mean by "produce" a convex cone, but I suspect you're referring to the fact that the **set** of positive semidefinite matrices forms a closed convex cone in $M_{n \times n}(\Bbb{R})$. Saying the rank constraint is non-convex just means the set of matrices satisfying the constraint (i.e. rank = 1) is not a convex set.

Comment: But aren't all matrices that belong to the set of rank 1 matrices PSD (and thus convex!)? I'm sorry that my question might be naive but it matters to me to be able to understand why $W=xx^T$ is PSD and thus convex. however, the rank($W$)=1 constraint is nonconvex?

Comment: A matrix cannot be convex. They are points in certain convex sets, but the property of convexity does not translate to the elements of convex sets. Yes, $xx^\top$ is PSD. Yes, this means they belong to the convex set of PSD matrices. No, this doesn't mean they are "convex" (in quotes, because this is meaningless in this context). Any matrix $M$ belongs to the convex set $\{M\}$, i.e. a singleton set (which are *always* convex). At the same time, $M \in \{M, M + I\}$, which is always a non-convex set. That is, belonging to a (non-)convex set are not mutually exclusive properties of matrices.

Comment: An analogy: the unit circle in $\Bbb{R}^2$ (i.e. the boundary circle, not the whole disc) is non-convex. The positive quadrant $\{(x, y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : x, y \ge 0\}$ is convex. These are subsets of a vector space $\Bbb{R}^2$, and so it makes sense to consider "convexity". On the other hand, the point $(0, 1)$ belongs to both sets. Is this point convex? Is it non-convex? Answer: neither, because the convexity of a point in vector space doesn't mean anything. Looking at individual matrices and asking about convexity is like picking on individual points in $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I'm starting to see your point. My question is, when I add the constraint $W\ge0$, What do I mean? Do I mean that the matrix W should be PSD? I know that this is a convex constraint. From what I understood from you, a matrix can't be convex or non convex but still, in a SDP problem, we add such constraint and we look for the elements of the W matrix that is PSD? Why is the constraint $W\ge0$ convex?

Comment: I think you do mean $W$ is PSD (using the [Loewner Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order)). And yes, $W \ge 0$ is a convex constraint, as the set of $W$ such that $W \ge 0$ (i.e. $W$ is PSD) is a convex set. Or, in other words, if $W_1, W_2 \ge 0$, and $\theta \in [0, 1]$, then $\theta W_1 + (1 - \theta)W_2 \ge 0$. We can't say the same if $W_1$ and $W_2$ are rank-1 though. Even being rank-1 AND PSD will not suffice to make $\theta W_1 + (1 - \theta)W_2$ rank-1. This is what makes it a non-convex constraint.

Comment: I understand your point now. I'm very thankful!

Comment: You're welcome!